# Android, run a method from another class

Tags: android

My game needs to update the background of a TextView in every class onCreate to show the health of the player, however at the moment the only way i can think of doing it is this

```
int Health = 100;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_act1);

    if (Health == 100){
        HealthDisplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.health100);
    } else if (Health == 99){
        HealthDisplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.health99);
    } else if (Health == 98){
        HealthDisplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.health98);
    } else if (Health == 99){
        HealthDisplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.health98);
    } else if (Health == 99){
        HealthDisplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.health98);
    } else if (Health == 99){
        HealthDisplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.health98);
    }

etc.
}
```

There has to be an easier/ faster way of doing this, especially as i need to do similar for two other stats as well.

I have thought about having a separate class handle it and have a line or two in the onCreate that tells it to run that class to update the background image then return to this one.

Alternatively perhaps something like this is possible?

```
int Health = 100;

HealthDisplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.health(Health));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest is having one image (for full health) and each time crop it and show a percentage of it according to your health level. For example:

```
private ImageView healthLevel;
private ClipDrawable clipDrawable;
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            healthLevel = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.health);   //there a corresponding ImageView in the layout
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),    R.drawable.full_health));
            //vertical bar cropped from top
            clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(bitmapDrawable, Gravity.BOTTOM, ClipDrawable.VERTICAL);  
            healthLevel.setImageDrawable(clipDrawable);
    }
```

and then in another thread you would call:

```
int health = 54;
clipDrawable.setLevel(health);
clipDrawable.invalidateSelf();
```

Answer (score 0):

"My game needs to update the background of a TextView in every class onCreate to show the health of the player"

Sorry I don't understand. If you want to update the background at runtime don't do it in onCreate as it is called only once (when the activity is created).

Just create a method that will update this background by calling setBackgroundResource on the TextView.

Comment: Its only a textbased game that changes class each time a radiobutton selection is made, so updating in the oncreate is fine because the classes will change every time an action is taken.

I guess im also asking for help on how to create the method, preferably without having a huge chunk of code in every class

Comment: onCreate is for Activities. So you are saying you are creating an activity each time you press a button?

Comment: yes, because the game is so simple and limited (maximum of 3 choices per class so 1. go up stairs 2. go down 3. cry) its easier to keep up to date if the code is separated into a different class per action taken

Answer (score 0):

ThomasKa's answer is a good one. Cropping one resource will save you a lot of time, and looks good if done right. However, you *can* use 100 separate drawables if you want to.

What you want to do is name your drawables appropriately(with a number suffix), and grab them by name. You can use [`Resources.getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for that, something like:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int resId = res.getIdentifier("health" + Health, "drawable", getPackageName());
HealthDisplay.setBackgroundResource(resId);
```

The example assumes your drawables are named health100, health99, etc, as in your example.